# BlankNullSequence in Rule

Tags: replacement, rule

Why BlankNullSequence `rest___` is not matched with nothing (empty expression) ?

```
a^2 /. Times[rest___, x_^2] -> 2
(* a^2 *)

a^2 /. Plus[rest___, x_^2] :> 2
(* a^2 *)
```

Should not the answer be `2` in both cases ? How should be the pattern for that ?

Comment: The rule will not match because $a^2$ head is `Power`, and therefore will be ignored.

Comment: @AnjanKumar, So what is wrong with the head `Power` ? Both `a^2` and `x_^2` have the same head `Power`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking to match a pattern that has a head of `Times` and your expression has a head of `Power`.

Use something like:

```
a^2 /. Times[n_., x_^2] -> 2
```

to do what you require.  See the documentation for `Default` (`n_.`) and `OneIdentity`.  `OneIdentity` is the attribute of `Plus` and `Times` which tells Mathematica that `Times[x]` is the same as `x`.